Object Stretching Behind Bones
So I'm trying to rig a character's torso/stomach, but whenever I parent the shirt to the bones in the armature (with automatic weights), the object stretches behind the bones when I move them. I've made sure the object has good topology and no overlapping faces. I've also tried to weight paint for every bone, but it still stretches. I'm at a loss at what to do. (Not sure if it has anything to do with it, but the mirror modifier seems to be off center when I tried it)





Hello, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/ Also tell an example of bone that deforms the mesh

I'd prefer if I kept the model in just my hands, if I can. In the first picture I have the bones highlighted that I parented the mesh too, and the other pictures are of when I tried to move the bones
